# Connect: Connection refused error when connecting from laptop to PC

Tags: c, sockets, networking, tcp, firewall

For fun, I decided I wanted to make a small text service using sockets, but for some reason when I try to run the program from my laptop using WSL (server running on native Linux), it gives me an error

> Socket: Connection refused

However, when I run the code on my desktop, it works fine, and I can have multiple clients connected.

Here's the relevant parts of my code:

Client Side:

```
const char *node = argv[1];
const char *port = argv[2];
const char *name = argv[3];
// char *node = "127.0.0.1";
// char *port = "8568";
struct addrinfo hints;
memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
hints.ai_family=AF_INET;
hints.ai_socktype=SOCK_STREAM;
struct addrinfo *server;
int ret_val = getaddrinfo(node,port,&hints,&server);
if (ret_val != 0) {
    printf("getaddrinfo failed: %s\n", gai_strerror(ret_val));
}
int sock_fd = socket(server->ai_family,server->ai_socktype,server->ai_protocol);
if (sock_fd == -1) {
    perror("socket");
    freeaddrinfo(server);
    return 1;
}
if (connect(sock_fd, server->ai_addr, server->ai_addrlen) == -1) {
    perror("socket");
    freeaddrinfo(server);
    return 1;
}
freeaddrinfo(server);
```

Server Side:

```
// Handler for SIGINT - ensures proper cleanup
void handle_sigint(int signo) {
    keep_going = 0;
}

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    struct sigaction sigact;
    sigact.sa_handler = handle_sigint;
    sigfillset(&sigact.sa_mask);
    sigact.sa_flags = 0; // Note the lack of SA_RESTART
    if (sigaction(SIGINT, &sigact, NULL) == -1) {
        perror("sigaction");
        return 1;
    }

    char *port = "8568";
    struct addrinfo hints;
    memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(hints));
    hints.ai_family=AF_INET;
    hints.ai_socktype=SOCK_STREAM;
    struct addrinfo *server;
    int ret_val = getaddrinfo(NULL,port,&hints,&server);
    if (ret_val != 0) {
        printf("getaddrinfo failed: %s\n", gai_strerror(ret_val));
    }
    int sock_fd = socket(server->ai_family,server->ai_socktype,server->ai_protocol);
    if (sock_fd == -1) {
        perror("socket");
        freeaddrinfo(server);
        return 1;
    }
    if (bind(sock_fd, server->ai_addr, server->ai_addrlen) == -1) {
        perror("bind");
        freeaddrinfo(server);
        close(sock_fd);
        return 1;
    }
    freeaddrinfo(server);
    if (listen(sock_fd, LISTEN_QUEUE_LEN) == -1) {
        perror("listen");
        close(sock_fd);
        return 1;
    }
    int pipe_fds[LISTEN_QUEUE_LEN*2];
    int avail_id[LISTEN_QUEUE_LEN];
    for(int i = 0;i<LISTEN_QUEUE_LEN;i++){
        pipe(&pipe_fds[2*i]);
        avail_id[i]=1;
    } 
    while (keep_going != 0) {
        printf("Waiting for client to connect\n");
        int client_fd = accept(sock_fd, NULL, NULL);
        int id = 0;
        for(int i = 0;i<LISTEN_QUEUE_LEN;i++){
            if(avail_id[i]==1){
                id = i;
                avail_id[i]=0;
                break;
            }
        }
```

I've also made sure that port 8568 is open on my desktop and unblocked by the firewall. I'm not super familiar with firewalls, however, so I could have missed something.

Also, the server is running natively on Ubuntu on my desktop, and the client is running through WSL on my laptop.

Comment: Can you ping from WSL?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how to do that, I typed ping [IPADDRESS] and it did work, don't know how to ping the port though

Comment: Do `telnet <IPADDRESS> <PORT>` If it says `connection refused`, it is not listening.  If you have to type `^]` then port is listening.

Comment: One thing I notice - when the server code calls `getaddrinfo()`, it should be specifying the `AI_PASSIVE` flag in `hints.ai_flags`: "*If the `AI_PASSIVE` flag is specified in `hints.ai_flags`, and `node` is NULL, then the returned socket addresses will be suitable for `bind(2)`ing a socket that will `accept(2)` connections.*" - May or may not make a difference in your case, but it is something you should be doing nonetheless.

Comment: Just an FYI, in the client code, the 2nd `perror("socket");` should be `perror("connect");` instead.

Comment: Ok, I did telnet ipaddress port and it said connection refused. I also added the AI_PASSIVE flag but nothing changed. Any suggestions on where to go from here?

Comment: @MarcusRana So, you are trying to connect from a Linux client running in Windows WSL to a server running on Ubuntu. You say `ping` works, but `telnet` doesn't. That means that the WSL environment is not able to reach the listening port on Ubuntu. That sounds like a firewall/routing issue, not a coding issue. I see you [asked a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72119741/) about that on StackOverflow, but networking-related questions should be asked on [sf] instead. The code looks fine (once you apply the fixes mentioned), providing the client is connecting to the correct IP.